# Why do I celebrate later? (still 13,37 years)

Tags: riddle, calculation-puzzle, time

A very little time ago, just a bit ago one may say, people started partying. Some even went out of their houses to do so… crazy thing, IMHO.

Anyway, I don't, I'll start partying in 4886 days.¹
**Why do I do so?**

I could say in $13.37$ tropical years.²

*Note:* I do have another tag I could add later, which would make this riddle a lot easier, so I'll leave it for now.

---

Want another funny extra tip? Here it is:

> Hey, I could also say in $42.2163200 * 10^7$ seconds. Maybe I like the number seven?

In your answer, please state if you needed the tip…

---

¹ I know, I rounded a bit and had a 3 hour and 33⅓ minute error. That is scientifically acceptable though, because it is a funny number.
² I did that again, I know. I don't have an excuse right now though.
³ More hints³ are hidden in here, than you'd expect.⁴ (Extra points, if you can all explain all of them to me.)
⁴ Though not all of them may be useful. Another tip could be to also find out *who am I*.
⁵ 1 or 2, who cares. I am sometimes too slow.

Comment: Could you specify what comma system are you using with your numbers? I find it hard to read, or is it part of the riddle? (I am assuming it is analogous to a decimal point)

Comment: Sorry, not a part of the riddle. Corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you'll start partying in 4886 days because

> At 03:33:20 UTC on Wednesday, 18 May 2033, the Unix time value will equal 2000000000 seconds. Perhaps you like Unix time values in multiples of one billion.

I didn't use the tip but possibly

> You are hinting at converting the time to seconds.

Comment: Wow you even guessed the tip! That is awesome! 